# Better solution instead of $wire.set to pass computed Alpine value for livewire

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, alpine.js

I am new in Alpine / Livewire. This tag script works well expect one thing: the form is sending continiusly query to the server. Is better way to pass the form data for livewire?

```
<div class="col-span-6 my-2" x-data="{tags: [], newTag: ''}" >

    <x-jet-input id="tags"
                type="text"
                wire:model="tags"
                :value="$wire.set('tags','JSON.stringify(tags)')"
                class="mt-1 block w-full hidden"
                />

      <div class=" w-full mx-auto ">
          <div class="tags-input border-gray-300 shadow-sm  focus:ring focus:ring-indigo-200 focus:ring-opacity-50">

              <template x-for="tag in tags" :key="tag">
                  <span class="tags-input-tag">
                      <span x-text="tag"></span>
                      <button type="button" class="tags-input-remove" @click="tags = tags.filter(i => i !== tag)">
                          &times;
                      </button>
                  </span>
              </template>

              <input class="tags-input-text w-full" placeholder="{{__('Add music tags eg.') }} Pop Trap Live..."
                  @keydown.enter.prevent="if (newTag.trim() !== '') tags.push(newTag.trim()); newTag = ''"
                  @keydown.space.prevent="if (newTag.trim() !== '') tags.push(newTag.trim()); newTag = ''"
                  @keydown.backspace="if (newTag.trim() === '') tags.pop()"
                  x-model="newTag"
              />

      </div>
    <x-jet-input-error for="tags" class="mt-2" />
    <x-slot name="actions">

        <x-jet-action-message class="mr-3" on="saved">
            {{ __('Saved.') }}
        </x-jet-action-message>

        <x-jet-button
          >
            {{ __('Save') }}
        </x-jet-button>
    </x-slot>
```

Answer (score 0):

For everyone who has problem with $wire.set:
I find the solution and is not in documentation.
$wire.set need third parameter true to skip watch function and it won't send data in the background if no need
$wire.set('param','value',true)